# Analyzing continuous variable at different levels

Tags: interaction, continuous-data

for my thesis, I'm having difficulties on how to analyze my hypothesis. In a nutshell:

DV: evaluation of colonial history

IV: article (positive or negative description of colonial past) that participants have to read

moderator: ideology (on a continuous scale)

I'm suspecting a different result depending on whether the level of ideology is low, medium or high. Which analysis do I have to do? Process? I'm not sure how exactly I see the results for these 3 different levels via process.
Or do I have to split my continuous moderator into 3 categories? (which I would like to avoid if possible). Hope my question is clear, many thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to split it?

Comment: I don't want to split it if I can avoid it. I just want to analyze the continuous variable at different levels, and I don't see how I can do it when it's continuous. Can I do it via process?

Comment: But why do you want to use the levels instead of keeping it continuous, e.g. in regression model? By splitting it you loose information. Moreover, by doing so you make values like 1.999999999 and 2.00000000 be in distinct groups, instead being almost equal

Comment: Because I'm suspecting a different result depending on whether the level of ideology (moderator variable) is low, medium or high. But maybe I'm missing an important point here? How would you suggest that I can analyze it, by keeping it continuous? (sorry if the question is stupid, I'm just getting started).

Comment: Why keeping it continuous shouldn't let you to observe such effect?! By splitting it, you loose information. Why loosing information should give you more information about anything?

Comment: Can you tell me how I can observe this effect? With process? I'm aware that the question is really stupid and probably really simple, I'm just really lost right now:-)

Comment: With some kind of regression model (depending on what exactly your data is).

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I'm just really lost. I try to explain my hypothesis in a nutshell:

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I'm just really lost. I try to explain my hypothesis in a nutshell: - The article describing the colonial past will have an effect on how participants evaluate their colonial history, and this will be influenced by their ideology: 1) When the article is positive, people with a high level of ideology will evaluate their colonial past as more positive compared to those with a low and medium level, and more positive than they would in the condition "negative article".

Comment: 2) When the article is negative, people with a low level of ideology will evaluate their colonial past as more negative compared to those with a high and medium level, and more negative than they would in the condition "positive article". I hope it's clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By splitting your continuous variable into three groups you *loose information*. After splitting, the only information that is left is that low < medium < high, and still this is true only if you treat your variable as ordinal, otherwise your statistical model won't even "know" that there is any relation between the groups. Moreover, you loose information about the magnitude of changes. Say that your data variable is continuous and bounded in $[0, 1]$ and you split it into three groups: low $[0, 0.33)$, medium $[0.33, 0.66)$ and high $[0.66, 1]$, if you treat it s ordinal, then you assume that the difference between $0.32999999$ and $0.33$ is the same as between $0$ and $0.33$.

Instead, in almost all cases, you should rather use model that does not need you to do transformations that do not lead to information loss. The simple approach would be to use some kind of regression model (linear regression, logistic regression, Poisson regression etc., depending on your data) where the moderator variable would be *centered* by subtracting some kind of average from it. You could use any "average" that if meaningful for your analysis, e.g. mean, median, or some arbitrary value like the middle-point fo your scale. By doing so, values smaller then the average would lie below zero and values higher that it, would be above zero. If regression coefficient would be positive, then the "small" values of your variable would lead to decreasing your dependent variable and large ones to increasing it, so the effect would be easy to interpret. On another hand, negative coefficient would suggest that data is inconsistent with your hypothesis and shows the opposite effect. Relatively small values of coefficients would show that there is no noticeable relation between dependent and moderator variables. Moreover, the coefficient would tell you about the magnitude of the dependent variable given the moderator variable.

Notice that, as informally shown by Gelman, and Park (2009), linear regression leads to equivalent (but more precise!) results as splitting into the three groups.

> Gelman, A., & Park, D. K. (2009). [Splitting a predictor at the upper
>   quarter or third and the lower quarter or third.](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/thirds5.pdf) The American
>   Statistician, 63(1), 1-8.